# Why are election statistics only shown to moderators during the nomination phase?

Tags: support, bug, moderator-tools, election, statistics

When an election finishes, you can see a report with some [voter statistics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/4):

[image]

However, today I discovered that this information is also shown to ♦ moderators during an [ongoing election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5):

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Are we supposed to do anything with that information? Can't it be shared with the entire community? At least the number of (qualified) visitors can be determined by looking at [recently awarded Caucus badges](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/80). The number of eligible votes can probably be counted via the /users page or estimated with SEDE.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307153/make-the-mod-only-status-of-election-turnout-obvious#comment998852_307157

Comment: Recently noticed on SO, too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412426. Neither us mods nor the CMs that we checked with could think of any reason why this decision was made.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that MSE question because it was tagged [election-page] ... I've synonymized that tag now, since there were only very few questions actually about elections.stackexchange.com which is defunct anyway.